# breadcrumb navigation for dynamically generated data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table called `Nodes > (NodeID || ParentID || NodeName)` which has the category-subcategory hierarchy.

Here are some sample table data:

```
NodeID   || ParentID  ||  NodeName

1 ||  null || All Categories

2 || 1 || Category 1

3 || 1 || Category 2

4 || 2 || Sub- Category 1

5 || 4 || Sub-sub-category 1

5 || 3 || Sub-Category 2

6 || 5 || product 1
```

I would like to have the breadcrumb as anchors or something so that i can directly get the nodeID of the one clicked.

Now from this table nodes, I would like to make a bread-crumb depending on where am i on the table.

Here is what I am trying:

```
 Dim strCmd As String = "WITH abcd AS ( SELECT  nodeid, nodeName, ParentID, CAST(([nodeName]) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS Path FROM Nodes WHERE parentid = 1 UNION ALL SELECT  t.nodeid, t.[nodeName], t.ParentID, CAST(( a.path + ' > ' + '<a href=""products.aspx?id=' + CAST((t.nodeid) as Varchar) + '"">' + t.nodeName + '</a>') AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS Path FROM nodes AS t JOIN abcd AS a ON t.ParentId = a.nodeid )SELECT nodeid,nodename,path FROM abcd"
        Using _cmd As SqlCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT * FROM Nodes") 
            Using _dt As DataTable = db.ExecuteDataSet(_cmd).Tables(0)
                _dt.Columns.Add("BreadCrumb")
                Using ds1 As DataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, strCmd)
                    For i As Integer = 0 To _dt.Rows.Count - 1
                        Dim results = (From myRow As DataRow In ds1.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() Where (myRow.Field(Of Integer)("nodeId") = _dt.Rows(i).Item(0)) Select myRow.Field(Of String)("path")).SingleOrDefault()
                        _dt.Rows(i).Item(13) = results
                        Label1.Text += results & " <br/>"    'Just debug code, printing all the breadcrumbs on the page.
                    Next
                End Using

            End Using
        End Using
```

From the above code, I a getting my breadcrumb, but i am unable to put the first element of the breadcrumb into an anchor.

> Category 1
>
> Category 2
>
> Category 1 > [Sub- Category 1]
>
> Category 1 > [Sub- Category 1] > [Sub-sub-category1]
>
> Category 1 > [Sub-Category 2]
>
> Category 1 > [Sub- Category 1] > [Sub-sub-category1] > [product 1]

What I was looking for is a way to somehow get the first elements of the breadcrumb to be an anchor or something so that i can get the nodeid of the clicked element. I am not sure if there is a way for this to be done, I have spent a lot of time but unable to figure out a proper way. Please suggest me if there is anything that can be done, or should i use a different approach for the problem.

I hope this data is clear, please let me know if you need any other clarification.

Comment: I don't think you should generate HTML using SQL. At the very least you'll get unencoded HTML output that way.

Comment: yes i wont do that, this is just for this example i have done this. Ultimately i would want something which should behave like this only..

Comment: Can you please post the desired result from this query?

Comment: yes the desired result should be as in the 3rd block i have provided above. the elements in the square brackets [] have anchor tags, but i am unable to put an anchor tag around the first element.